# Proof for non-existence of multi variable limit of $2x\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2+2y^2}\right)/(x^2+2y^2)$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

How do I prove that the below limit doesn't exist:

$$\lim _{\left(x,\:\:y\right)\to \left(0,0\right)}\left(\frac{2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2+2y^2}\right)}{x^2+2y^2}\right)\cdot x$$

Its easy to see that: $$\lim _{\left(x,\:\:y\right)\to \left(0,0\right)}\left(\frac{2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2+2y^2}\right)}{x^2+2y^2}\right)\:=\:\lim _{t\to 0}\left(\frac{2\cos\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}{t}\right)$$
and that limit doesn't exist by Heine (if we took for example $t\:=\:\frac{1}{2\pi n}\:$), but then the left $x$ is bothering me to say that the whole limit doesn't exist, because it is the product of limit that 0 and limit that doesn't exist. And if I look at this as two equations in that way:
$$\lim \:_{\left(x,\:\:y\right)\to \:\left(0,0\right)}\left(\frac{x}{x^2+2y^2}\right)\: $$  and  $$\lim \:_{\left(x,\:\:y\right)\to \:\left(0,0\right)}\left(2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2+2y^2}\right)\right) $$
they both don't exist and then I can't say anything about their product either.
What is the right explanation here, without using the definition in language of $\epsilon ,\:\delta $ and that stuff.

Comment: Look at what happens as $x$ approaches the origin along the $x$-axis. Note that $\left|\frac{x}{x^2}\right|$ blows up.

Comment: Yes, but: $$\lim \:\:_{\left(x,\:\:y\right)\to \:\:\left(0,0\right)}\left|\left(\frac{x}{x^2+2y^2}\right)\:\right|\:<\:\lim \:\:\:_{\left(x,\:\:y\right)\to \:\:\:\left(0,0\right)}\:\left|\frac{x}{x^2}\right|$$
 So it doesnt give anything in that way.

Comment: Even if you want to say that:
$$\lim _{\left(x\:,\:y\right)\to \left(0,0\right)}  \left(\frac{\left|\left(\frac{x}{x^2+2y^2}\right)\:\right|}{\:\left|\frac{x}{x^2}\right|}\right) $$
And because of that "similiar behaviar at (0,0)" it diverges. Ok, I already wrote about that, but the cos also diverges and formally you can not to say anything about the product of two diverging limits. 

Otherwise I didnt understand what is your idea.

Comment: You should be looking at $$\frac{2x\cos\frac{1}{x^2}}{x^2}\;,$$ i.e., at what happens when $y=0$.

Comment: Wait a minute, I think I got it. Your intent was to take (x,0) as a path - "along the x-axis". Ok

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Yes, and then by taking a specific serie we can show that the limit of f(n) diverges, therefore the limit of f(x) doesnt exist, right ? ( where $f\left(x\right)\:=\:\frac{2cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{x}$)
For example: $$a_n\:=\:\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$$

Comment: The function has a value at every point except the origin, but the *limit* as $x\to 0$ doesn't exist. Yes, that sequence works fine.

Comment: Yes, i just wrote the explanation, why it isnt exist in 0. The proof is by taking series and $a_n$ that converges to the value 0 but $f(a_n)$ diverges therefore the $f(x)$ diverges too (by Heine). That the whole explanation, as I understand.

Comment: Thats it, thanks. Looking like we complete each other sentences. Have a nice day )

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: It seems that this question was settled in the comments. @user183297 Perhaps you could post an answer based on the Brian M. Scott's suggestions from the comments.

Comment: Martin, just noticed that. Alex wrote it as we disscussed.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to approach the origin along different sequences in the hope that the limits along these sequences will be different (or will not even exist).

First, along the sequence $(0,\frac 1 n)$ the function is constant $0$, so its limit will also be $0$.

Choose now the trajectory given by $y=x$, and, for simplicity, $x>0$. Along it, your function will be $\frac 2 {3x} \cos \frac 1 {3x^2}$. This doesn't tell us anything yet, so let us fabricate a convenient formula for $x$: choose $x_n = \frac 1 {\sqrt {6 n \pi}}$. Clearly $(x_n, x_n) \to (0,0)$ and in $(x_n, x_n)$ the function becomes $\frac {2 \sqrt {6 n \pi}} 3$, which tends to $\infty$.

You have obtained the limits $0$ and $\infty$ along different sequences, therefore the limit does not exist.

Comment: As I remember, in case of $\infty$ its enough to say that it isnt exist, because if its exist its final (any number but not infinite). But maybe you right and I need to show 2 diffrent limits. Anyway from that point its pretty easy, thanks. Thats exactly what we have disscussed above (it was erased somehow).

Comment: @user183297: No, when the limit is $\infty$, it is considered to exist. Think of $\frac 1 x :(0,1] \to (0,\infty)$: the limit for $x \to 0$ exists very well and is $\infty$. Similarly, $\lim \limits _{x \to \infty} x = \infty$, again it exists.